# Parsing an object that is a string within an object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a large nested json object and within the nested json is an unparsed json object. How would I need to approach parsing that string within the already parse object?

Comment: Pass the property value to `JSON.parse(parsedObject.jsonStringProperty)`.

Comment: so `JSON.parse(myobject.attribute)` ?

Comment: Yes, but note that it doesn't reset the property value. It _returns_ the parsed structure.

Comment: SO that would only return the section I parsed

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can code `myobject.attribute = JSON.parse(myobject.attribute)` and the JSON string is replaced with the parsed structure.